# XSLT - How to get distinct element names from XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to get the distinct element names from my XML file using XSLT-1.0.

XML:

```
<forms>
  <form1>
       <metadata>
         <c1>some value</c1>
         <c2>some value</c2>
       </metadata>
       <set>
         <subset1>
             <c3>some value</c3>
             <c4>some value</c4>
             <c5>some value</c5>
         </subset1>
         <subset2>
             <c3>some value</c3>
             <c4>some value</c4>
             <c6>some value</c6>
         </subset2>
       </set>               
  </form1>
  <form2>
   ...
  </form2>
</forms>
```

My output should look like below when I pass the form name to the XSLT. For example, if I pass "form1" it should get me the distinct data elements available inside my `<form1>` tag like this:

> c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6

Also, I tried this XSLT and its returning this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select=
   "//*/*/*[not(../following::*/*
                       [not(name() = name(current()))]
               )
           ]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' ')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

> set1, set2, subset1, subset2, c3, c4, c6

Expected output:

> c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6

Also, how to pass my form name (i.e. `form1`) to my XSLT?

Comment: What defines a "data element"?

Comment: I meant element only (i.e. nodes... <c1>, <c2>, <c3> etc...)

Comment: `set1` is an element too. On what basis should it be excluded? --- P.S. Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? You could really use an extension function here, if you want to limit the result to a specific branch.

Comment: I need this output: c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6. Also, I am using c# to transform this.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I am asking what is the logic that needs to be applied to get that result.

Comment: Ok. I added some more details now. I actually need the "metadata" elements followed by "set/subset" elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a list of distinct names of all elements in the entire document is relatively easy - as shown in the answer by Dan Field.

Restricting the list to elements that are either children of `metadata` or grandchildren of `set` is slightly more complicated.

Restricting the list further to include only elements that are descendants of a  specific `form`, to be determined at runtime, is *much* more complicated.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="selected-form-name">form1</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="data" match="*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/forms">
    <xsl:variable name="selected-form" select="*[name()=$selected-form-name]"/>
    <!-- all names in the selected form -->
    <xsl:variable name="names-in-form">
        <xsl:for-each select="$selected-form/metadata/* | $selected-form/set/*/* " >
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </name>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- distinct elements (by name), in the entire document -->
    <xsl:variable name="distinct-by-name" select="//*[count(. | key('data', name())[1]) = 1]" />
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="$distinct-by-name[name()=exsl:node-set($names-in-form)/name]">
            <item><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<forms>
  <form1>
       <metadata>
         <c1>some value</c1>
         <c2>some value</c2>
       </metadata>
       <set>
         <subset1>
             <c3>some value</c3>
             <c4>some value</c4>
             <c5>some value</c5>
         </subset1>
         <subset2>
             <c3>some value</c3>
             <c4>some value</c4>
             <c6>some value</c6>
         </subset2>
       </set>               
  </form1>
   <form2>
      <metadata>
         <c7>some value</c7>
         <c8>some value</c8>
      </metadata>
      <set>
         <subset3>
             <c9>some value</c9>
             <c7>some value</c7>
         </subset3>
      </set>               
   </form2>
</forms>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item>c1</item>
   <item>c2</item>
   <item>c3</item>
   <item>c4</item>
   <item>c5</item>
   <item>c6</item>
</output>
```

---

To select the required form, pass a parameter named `selected-form-name` to the stylesheet, with the name of the form to select. If you pass the string `"form2"`, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <item>c7</item>
   <item>c8</item>
   <item>c9</item>
</output>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a key of local-names, and then do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:key name="elements" match="*" use="local-name()" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[count(.|key('elements', local-name())[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />, 
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically, doing Muenchian grouping against the element names.

Comment: To get the **exact** output try `<xsl:for-each select="//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'c') and count(.|key('elements', local-name())[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />, </xsl:for-each>`

Comment: @zx485 That's not the logic indicated by OP in comments.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks! This doesn't answer my question completely but definitely helped me a lot.